# How to delete a class in Salesforce DX using CLI

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I am trying to remove classes and pages from my scratch org. I have removed them my local repo and did sfdx force:source:push but I am getting the below error. Any idea how to resolve?

ERROR:  Path must be a string. Received undefined.

Comment: seems like you have broken up a dependency in some code .That's giving you the issue .What's the full error ?

Comment: I've seen this error message when trying to push source code which contains a *.resource-meta.xml file without a corresponding file or folder which is the static resource.